# Automapper ValueTransformers from dynamic to a class

Tags: c#, automapper

My project is using AutoMapper to convert from a dynamic object to a concrete class object.  Each concrete class has multiple string properties that I want trimmed by AutoMapper.  There are dozens of these concrete classes and setting up a CustomTypeConverter for each mapping is tedious.  I was hoping to achieve this with a ValueConverter, such as the following:

Here is my mapper config:

```
Mapper.Initialize(config =>
{
  config.ValueTransformers.Add<string>(val => val.Trim());
});
```

Here is one of my DTOs:

```
public class MyDto
{
  public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my method where I'm mapping from a dynamic to MyDto:

```
public async Task<object> MyMethod(dynamic input)
{
  MyDto dto = Mapper.Map<MyDto>(input);
  // expect dto.MyProperty to be trimmed here, but it is not.
  // do work
}
```

Is my base understanding of ValueTransformers incorrect here?  Do I have explicitly add a CustomTypeConverter for each DTO I'm mapping and use ForMember for each property that I need trimmed?

Comment: You can create a map from string to string instead.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that in the moment of being mapped the type of that property is not yet a string (because of the dynamic)? Not sure how to test it though, maybe you can do a quick test with a normal class.

If that would be the case, you could use some reflection in the `AfterMap` to cycle through all the string properties and trim them.

Something like this (this is an example for setting Dates as UTC, but you could adapt it) :

```
    public static class DateKindHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Scans an object for all its properties, and sets the kind of DateTime and DateTime? ones to UTC.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="target">Any object, preferably POCO ones.</param>
        public static void SetAllDateTimeValuesAsUtc(object target)
        {
            if (target == null) return;

            // TODO: We could add a propertyInfo list cache in a static dictionary for each type, so it's faster.

            //Extract all DateTime properties of the object type
            var properties = target.GetType().GetProperties()
                .Where(property => property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) ||
                                   property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?)).ToList();
            //Set all DaetTimeKinds to Utc
            properties.ForEach(property => SpecifyUtcKind(property, target));
        }

        private static void SpecifyUtcKind(PropertyInfo property, object value)
        {
            // If the property doesn't have a setter, we don nothing!
            if (property.SetMethod == null) return;

            //Get the datetime value
            var datetime = property.GetValue(value, null);

            //set DateTimeKind to Utc
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                datetime = DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime)datetime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            }
            else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
            {
                var nullable = (DateTime?)datetime;
                if (!nullable.HasValue) return;
                datetime = (DateTime?)DateTime.SpecifyKind(nullable.Value, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

            //And set the Utc DateTime value
            property.SetValue(value, datetime, null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This defeats the purpose of AM.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu - At this point, I've abandoned the automapper solution entirely, so I don't think this answer is off the mark at all.